# Why does this Textbox in a WinForms application break?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous

I am reading a book by Jeffrey Richter, CLR via C# 4th edition. Included in the book the author discusses asynchronous programming and points out a problem in GUI applications, such as WinForms or WPF applications, where an async method is called synchronously, which results in blocking of the GUI thread.

I created an out of the box WinForms app in Visual Studio 2015 and typed in a method that is discussed in the book. The code gets a Task that the Form then uses the Result property of to set a Textbox that is on the Form. I included the partial class definition for the Form below.

The problem is after performing this the TextBox becomes broken. By broken I mean it is impossible to type into the Textbox. Additionally the TextBox doesn't actually display the text after setting Text property of the TextBox. I don't believe the problem lies with the code in Richter's book. After all running the application in the debugger I can actually see the html of the page requested as a string.

Why does the TextBox break?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.MaxLength = 0;
        string page = GetHttp().Result;
        textBox1.Text = page;


    }           

    private Task<String> GetHttp()
    {

       return Task.Run(async () =>
       {
           // Issue the HTTP request and let the thread return from GetHttp
           HttpResponseMessage msg = await new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://www.techspot.com");
           return await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       });   

    }
}
```

Comment: A RichTextBox displays the string fine, if that is useful.

Comment: Remove `Task.Run` it is useless

Comment: MaxLength=0, what do you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the Textbox was a single line Textbox. Making the Textbox a multiline Textbox (which I omitted to do, slap's forehead) results in the code functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the `MaxLength` property on the TextBox.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference though. I thought the problem may have been due to the length of the string returned, since it exceeds the 32,767 limit for a WinForms Textbox as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

For clarification your code doesn't run async. You don't implement the async/await pattern the right way here. If you use `GetHttp().Result;` you can become Deadlock because .Result blocks and waits for your Task to complete. Instead you should use await to make sure your Task is completed. Further await doesn't block your UI and won't cause a Deadlock. I prepared your Code and using right names conventions:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Notice that .Result or .Wait on Gui-Thread can cause a Deadlock!!!
    string page = await GetHttpAsync();
    textBox1.Text = page;
}           

private async Task<String> GetHttpAsync()
{
   //Make sure you don't need any Task here. The await makes this async
   HttpResponseMessage msg = await new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://www.techspot.com");
   return await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

That your Textbox is broken is fact if you set `MaxLength = 0`like @Joel Coehoorn writes above or forget the MultiLine part if you mentioned. I hope this post is helpful to you although your question is answered.